# Battery test on Areca ARC-1231

Tags: raid

I have a system built around an ARC-1231, and since a few days, the battery is always shown as "Charging (96%)". As this looks fishy to me, I'd like to test the battery.

As I haven't found anything about running a battery test in the manual, I wonder how other people have done that. Disconnect and discharge via resistor and multimeter?

Comment: This is normal. "Charging" also includes float charging, which the controller always does. The "96%" is an estimate of the charge level.

Comment: How old is it?  Is it li-ion?  If it is 2-3years old, and is not normally charging to full, that is a specific indication that the battery is going bad. There are 4 other ways to get clues about a li-ion going bad, and many factors that can confuse the issue, but if the battery is Old, it is almost a waste of time to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Well nowdays, laptop makers include softwares (eg - "Dell extended battery") which try to increase the battery life of the battery.
One of its features is that it does not allow the battery to be charged to 100% (it charges between 92 - 97%) so that the battery's AC charge cycles are managed.
That may be the case with your laptop.

Comment: FYI: An ARC-1231 is a RAID controller from Areca. It has an on-board battery to allow it to write the contents of its own cache memory to disk in case of power failures. It is unlikely to come with 'extend your battery life programs' since the goal of these cards is performance over longer-then-corporate-lifecycle-battery-life.